# Simple ng-include's not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use a ng-include to include a template within a template in a component, the folder structure is as follows

```
-DE

--de

---test.html

-template.html
```

template.html content

```
<div>
<ng-include src "'/DE/de/test.html''"></ng-include>
</div>
```

This is what I get rendered in the page html

```
<!-- ngInclude: undefined -->
```

EDIT

I've edited the html as follows

```
    <ng-include src="'/DE/de/test.html'"></ng-include>
```

Still getting the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ng-include result in undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249684/using-ng-include-result-in-undefined)

Comment: Is your template from the same domain and protocol as the application document?

Comment: They are included in the same folder, however I didn't add them to the route provider and I'm assuming this is not needed, is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have several mistakes in the posted code:

- Missing equal sign for the `src` attribute
- Extra single quote inside the path value

NOTE : you do not need single quotes, the value of the src attribute is assumed to be a string

Fixed version:

```
<div>
    <ng-include src="/DE/de/test.html"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: I've fixed the issues you've mentioned, still the same issue but with the following error in the Network tab in the dev tools 'Cannot GET /DE/de/test.html'

Comment: _you do note need single quotes_ -- yes you do, otherwise it will be considered as an expression.

Comment: Yup, still I tried it with and without the quotes, with and without the leading slash and still got the same output !

Answer (score 0):

Starting the path with a slash `/` makes it as absolute path. This should work fine till your app's root is pointing to same folder in which `template.html` is put.

But, if that's not the case, you need to use relative path to make it work:

```
<ng-include src="'DE/de/test.html'"></ng-include>
```

This way, AngularJS fetches the source file, with path relative to the current folder.

Comment: I tried this solution as well, still having the same issue

Comment: @user1712638 -- I just realized that the string needs to be in single-quotes. Can you retry with it?

Comment: Tried it, same output